# How do I run transactions in CakePHP3 while retrieving last insert id and work for both PostgreSQL and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, cakephp, transactions, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3.x

[There is a way to execute transactions in CakePHP 3.x](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions).

However, some of my execute statements require the id of the previous insert statements.

How do I perform that in a transaction while choosing CakePHP 3.x and allowing either PostgreSQL or MySQL as my database?

My expected query is like this:

```
INSERT INTO dynamic_views (`title`, `created`) values ('view 37', NOW());

-- take the id of the above insert query and assuming the view id is 37
INSERT INTO users_access_dynamic_views(user_id, view_id) values (44, 37);
```

I would like to perform the above using transaction using CakePHP3.x.

At the same time, I would like to ask if using transaction for the above situation is it considered a bad idea?

Comment: This is a perfect example for a transaction.

Comment: Okay, then how do I retrieve the last insert id for the first query so I can run it on the second query for transaction to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After executing an insert query, you can call `lastInsertId()` with the right arguments to get the correct value:

```
$connection->transactional(function ($connection) {
    $statement = $connection->newQuery
        ->insert($fields)
        ->into($table)
        ->values($values)
        ->execute();

     $insertId = $statement->lastInsertId($table, 'id'); // id is primary key
});
```

Comment: I suppose I need to do it like this: `function ($connection) use ($fields, $table, $values)`??

Comment: Yeah, you pass the arguments you need to pass :)

Comment: Would you suggest I use transaction for this scenario? or you would suggest using afterSave or use if statement to check if the first insertion is successful? Because I cannot find saveAssociated in Cake3 docs. so I am not sure how to do that instead.

Comment: `save()` in CakePHP 3 also saves associations. Additionally, save always run inside a transaction.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I realized I cannot use associations as the second insert requires weird right outer joins. Can I still use Cake3 ORM to write the right outer join, or should I just use raw query? my right outher join is like this `INSERT INTO users_access_dynamic_views (dynamic_view_id, user_id, ordinal_ranking) 
SELECT ?, u.user_id, COUNT(uav.id) + 1 from users_access_dynamic_views uav
  RIGHT JOIN users_in_circles u ON uav.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.circle_id = ?
GROUP BY u.user_id`

Answer (score 1):

The function to get the last inserted id in MySQL is called [last_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), while in PostgreSQL it is [lastval()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-sequence.html). So either you have to create some mapping between the two, or you have to check which driver you are using in CakePHP and then call the specific function.

For example, you can create the following function in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION last_insert_id() RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
  SELECT lastval();
$$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

Then you can call it in the second query and it will work both in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

```
INSERT INTO users_access_dynamic_views
  (user_id, view_id)
VALUES
  (44, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Mind also that PostgreSQL uses sequences to generate IDs, so relying simply on `lastval` might produce unexpected results when there are triggers involved (inserting data somewhere on their own). So, it is always better to specify the sequence involved explicitly through `currval`.

```
CURRVAL(PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('dynamic_views', 'view_id'))
```